# Displaying HTML code based on condition JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to display `div` based on the availability of data using JSP. My issue is even if when the condition is valid, and the corresponding block responsible for showing the `div` executes, I am not able to view the said section rendered in my web page.

```
<body>
     <form>
          <h3>Order Type</h3>
          <div id="orderType" class="specialOrder">
            <table>
                <tr><td><label id="numberLabelId" for="numberId">Number</label>
                     <input type="text" name="number" id="numberId" onchange="processInput()"/>
                     <input type="hidden" name="groupSize" value="1" id="groupSizeId"/>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
            <%
                boolean dataReceived = false;
                boolean isQualified = false;
                String qualificationMessage = "";
                String error = "";

                if(request.getParameter("json") != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Response: " + request.getParameter("json"));

                    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(request.getParameter("json"));
                    MPQResponse mpqResponse = (MPQResponse) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, MPQResponse.class);

                    isQualified = mpqResponse.isQualified();
                    qualificationMessage = mpqResponse.isQualified() ? "Number is qulified for porting": "Number is not qualified for porting";
                    error = mpqResponse.getErrorMessage();
                    dataReceived = true;

                    System.out.println("Qualification status: " + qualificationMessage);
                    System.out.println("Error: " + error);
                }
            %>
            <%
                if(dataReceived && isQualified)
                {
            %>
                 <div><%=qualificationMessage%>/div>
                 <script type="text/javascript" >
                     refreshPage();
                 </script>
           <%
                }
                else
                {
           %>
                <div><%=qualificationMessage%></div>
                <div><%=error%></div>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </form>
</body>
```

The above is part of my code; in the above section, even `dataReceived` and `isQualified` is `true` the `div` section within this block does not render (I can see the code enters the block with the use of a debugger). What am I doing wring? I tried with JTL `<c:if>` still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div><%=qualificationMessage%>/div>
```

to

```
<div><%=qualificationMessage%></div>
```

close div is bad formatted, it's missing `<` symbol

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed that but the is still there. Plus I experimented with static text within the `div` tag, static text shows buy the JSP expression is null.

Comment: It may be related to that refreshPage.

Comment: I tried removing the `refreshPage()` too, but no luck. It's just that JSP expressions are not evaluating to the new value, even though I can clearly see the value is being in evaluated using the debugger